# Should I use Mix.Utils in my elixir code?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I need to get a file by URL and store it on the local disk.

I see that Mix.Utils has:

```
copy_path!(source, target, opts \\ [])
```

Which seems to do exactly what I want, but is Mix.Utils only something you'd use for writing mix tasks and not for general problem solving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which seems to do exactly what I want, but is Mix.Utils only something you'd use for writing mix tasks and not for general problem solving?

Typically yes. If you want to use it though, you need to depend on the `:mix` application in your `mix.exs` file inside the `def application` function.

Comment: Do you know of any other way of achieving what I want to do without using Mix.Utils?

Comment: No, you would have to write it yourself. It is short actually if you use a proper http client. The code in Mix has to deal with other complexities.

Comment: The other way you could do it would be to shell out and use curl or wgets to get the file for you.  But that could be done in any language; nothing specific to Elixir there.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci that was my fall back to just use cURL :) seems a bit dirty though.. Is executing system commands viewed as bad in the erlang/elixir world?

Comment: I may take a look at the code in the Mix.Utils function and see if I can lift it out and utilise what I need

Comment: "Bad"?  I am a software engineer; I don't deal in bad and good :)  I just deal in more or less appropriate.  If shelling out to a prebuilt command works for you, why reinvent working code?  On the other hand, shelling out to a prebuilt command leaves you at the mercy of the tool maintainer and the system admin etc. etc.